# verifying signature of apache release files

Tags: jmeter, rsa, signature, pgp

In most of the places, it is mentioned that either "RSA Key ID" or "DSA Key ID" should be used for receiving the public keys. http://www.apache.org/info/verification.html

For one of the packages downloaded, [jmeter](http://jmeter.apache.org/download_jmeter.cgi), there is no "KEY ID", there is only "RSA Key". What does this indicate? Any idea how to verify signature using RSA Key ?

Below is a sample output:

```
gpg --verify apache-jmeter-5.3.zip.asc apache-jmeter-5.3\ \(1\).zip 
gpg: Signature made Monday 11 May 2020 01:34:58 AM IST
gpg:                using RSA key C4923F9ABFB2F1A06F08E88BAC214CAA0612B399
gpg: Can't check signature: No public key
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Download JMeter (as per [9 Easy Solutions for a JMeter Load Test “Out of Memory” Failure](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/9-easy-solutions-jmeter-load-test-%E2%80%9Cout-memory%E2%80%9D-failure) you should always be using the latest version, current version is [JMeter 5.3](http://www.jmeter-archive.org/ANNOUNCE-Apache-JMeter-5-3-released-td5728863.html))

   ```
   wget -q https://downloads.apache.org//jmeter/binaries/apache-jmeter-5.3.tgz
   ```
2. Download the PGP key:

   ```
   wget -q https://www.apache.org/dist/jmeter/binaries/apache-jmeter-5.3.tgz.asc
   ```
3. Check the downloaded bundle against the key:

   ```
   gpg --verify apache-jmeter-5.3.tgz.asc apache-jmeter-5.3.tgz
   ```

   if you're getting `No public key` message it means that this `C4923F9ABFB2F1A06F08E88BAC214CAA0612B399` key is not known at your local machine, you need to import it from [PGP servers](https://superuser.com/questions/227991/where-to-upload-pgp-public-key-are-keyservers-still-surviving), i.e. from https://sks-keyservers.net/

   ```
   gpg --keyserver hkp://pool.sks-keyservers.net  --receive-keys C4923F9ABFB2F1A06F08E88BAC214CAA0612B399
   ```
4. Once done you should be able to repeat step 3 successfully

   [image]